# Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, opencl, unsatisfiedlinkerror, arrayfire

I am currently trying to build and run this project: https://github.com/arrayfire/androidcl on the AT&T Samsung Galaxy S3. The problem is when I try running: ./ndk-build -C ~/Desktop/ArrayFire/androidcl/jni

Then I try to run it on the phone by going to "Run -> Run as -> Android Application."

I get an "Unfortunately, droidcl has stopped working." I am quite the noob, but after days of researching, I think it has to do with the NDK. On line 19 at LiveFeatureActivity, "System.loadLibrary("JNIProcessor");" is my biggest suspicion.

All the files are on Git. Help would be appreciated as I tried to run it for 3 days but to no avail.

Here is what ndk-build says:

```html
./ndk-build -C ~/Desktop/ArrayFire/androidcl/jni
Android NDK: WARNING:/home/laptop/Desktop/ArrayFire/androidcl/jni/Android.mk:JNIProcessor: non-system libraries in linker flags: /usr/lib/libOpenCL.so    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
make: Entering directory `/home/laptop/Desktop/ArrayFire/androidcl/jni'
[armeabi] Compile++ arm  : JNIProcessor <= processor.cpp
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libJNIProcessor.so
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: /usr/lib/libOpenCL.so: No such file or directory
make: *** [/home/laptop/Desktop/ArrayFire/androidcl/obj/local/armeabi/libJNIProcessor.so] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/laptop/Desktop/ArrayFire/androidcl/jni'
```

Here is the Android.mk:

```html
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := JNIProcessor
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := processor.cpp
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -DARM -DOS_LNX -DARCH_32 -fexceptions
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS  += -fexceptions
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -ljnigraphics -llog $(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/libOpenCL.so
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I tried going into the Android.mk file and pointing directly to /usr/lib/libOpenCl.so (which after checking the library is there) but still doesn't work.

Here is the logcat file:

```html
02-06 22:52:27.515: D/ActivityThread(3233): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
02-06 22:52:27.515: D/ActivityThread(3233): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
02-06 22:52:27.515: D/ActivityThread(3233): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
02-06 22:52:27.575: W/dalvikvm(3233): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/example/LiveFeatureActivity;
02-06 22:52:27.575: W/dalvikvm(3233): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/example/LiveFeatureActivity;)
02-06 22:52:27.575: D/AndroidRuntime(3233): Shutting down VM
02-06 22:52:27.575: W/dalvikvm(3233): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40cb6300)
02-06 22:52:27.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3233): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 22:52:27.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3233): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
02-06 22:52:27.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3233):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-06 22:52:27.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3233):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
02-06 22:52:27.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3233):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
02-06 22:52:27.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3233):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2090)
02-06 22:52:27.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3233):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
02-06 22:52:27.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3233):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)
02-06 22:52:27.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3233):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
02-06 22:52:27.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3233):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-06 22:52:27.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3233):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-06 22:52:27.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3233):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
02-06 22:52:27.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3233):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 22:52:27.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3233):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-06 22:52:27.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3233):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
02-06 22:52:27.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3233):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
02-06 22:52:27.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3233):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-06 22:52:27.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3233): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load JNIProcessor: findLibrary returned null
02-06 22:52:27.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3233):  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
02-06 22:52:27.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3233):  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
02-06 22:52:27.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3233):  at com.example.LiveFeatureActivity.<clinit>(LiveFeatureActivity.java:19)
02-06 22:52:27.575: E/AndroidRuntime(3233):  ... 15 more
02-06 22:52:43.723: I/Process(3233): Sending signal. PID: 3233 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UnsatisfiedLinkError` you receive when running the app is simply because your module failed to build, and therefore wasn't included in the app. Getting the NDK build to link against a `libOpenCL.so` should solve this.

You first need to acquire a `libOpenCL.so` to link against, which you should be able to find on the target device (if it isn't there, then this application won't work anyway). On my devices, the OpenCL library is in `/system/vendor/lib/libOpenCL.so`, but you may need to poke around with `adb shell` to find it. To copy it to your local machine run `adb pull /system/vendor/lib/libOpenCL.so`.

If you put this library in your `jni/` directory, then you should just need to have `libOpenCL.so` in your `LOCAL_LDLIBS` variable. Otherwise, I usually just stick a copy of this library in the NDK platform directory (e.g. `$NDK_DIR/platforms/android-17/arch-arm/usr/lib/`), and then it is available to all applications to use by adding `-lOpenCL` to your `LOCAL_LDLIBS variable`. In both cases, you'll probably get a warning about non-system libraries in your linker flags, but these should be safe to ignore.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the clarification! So I found the libOpenCL.so file at /usr/lib. I tried copying it over to the located but it won't let me. The file is in red coloring (Ubuntu terminal), while the other "regular" libraries are colored cyan like they are supposed to. Am I supposed to "sudo ldconfig" something to create the needed library?

Comment: @Cookiez How were you trying to copy the file? Did you find `libOpenCL.so` in `/usr/lib` on your own machine, or on the phone's filesystem (i.e. via `adb shell`)?

Comment: Ah, turns out the library is broken (hence the red coloring and not light blue). But anyways, I found libOpenCL.so on my own machine, not through adb shell. But I also tried digging around through adb shell but still nothing (ran "find / libOpenCL.so") and manually checked too.

Comment: Have you verified that your phone actually supports OpenCL? e.g. can you run one of the OpenCL Info applications from the app store? Looking at the specs of the Galaxy S3, I'm not convinced that it can.

Comment: Oh you're right. The S3 doesn't have OpenCL support! I will get another mobile device soon. I thought the Mali GPU would support it but it is only certain models. But I have learned. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

@Cookiez Not sure if you stumbled upon this repository through Google search or after reading the blog post i wrote about it. In case you are not aware of the post, please go through [this](http://arrayfire.com/getting-started-with-opencl-on-android/) post on how to get the code running on an Android device. Let me know if you still can't get the app running.

Pradeep.

Comment: Yup, I've read that post already. That's how I got everything set up :) I finally got the app up and running! Thanks for your help guys.